# Reindexing and filling on one level of a hierarchical index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a two level hierarchical index ('item_id' and 'date'). Each row has columns for a variety of metrics for a particular item in a particular month. Here's a sample:

```
                    total_annotations  unique_tags
date       item_id
2007-04-01 2                       30           14
2007-05-01 2                       32           16
2007-06-01 2                       36           19
2008-07-01 2                       81           33
2008-11-01 2                       82           34
2009-04-01 2                       84           35
2010-03-01 2                       90           35
2010-04-01 2                      100           36
2010-11-01 2                      105           40
2011-05-01 2                      106           40
2011-07-01 2                      108           42
2005-08-01 3                      479          200
2005-09-01 3                      707          269
2005-10-01 3                      980          327
2005-11-01 3                     1176          373
2005-12-01 3                     1536          438
2006-01-01 3                     1854          497
2006-02-01 3                     2206          560
2006-03-01 3                     2558          632
2007-02-01 3                     5650         1019
```

As you can see, there are not observations for all consecutive months for each item. What I want to do is reindex the dataframe such that each item has rows for each month in a specified range. Now, this is easy to accomplish for any given item. So, for item_id 99, for example:

```
baseDateRange = pd.date_range('2005-07-01','2013-01-01',freq='MS')
data.xs(99,level='item_id').reindex(baseDateRange,method='ffill')
```

But with this method, I'd have to iterate through all the item_ids, then merge everything together, which seems woefully over-complicated.

So how can I apply this to the full dataframe, ffill-ing the observations (but also the item_id index) such that each item_id has properly filled rows for all the dates in baseDateRange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially for each group you want to reindex and ffill. The apply gets passed a data frame that has the item_id and date still in the index, so reset, then set and reindex with filling.
idx is your baseDateRange from above.

```
In [33]: df.groupby(level='item_id').apply(
      lambda x: x.reset_index().set_index('date').reindex(idx,method='ffill')).head(30)
Out[33]: 
                    item_id  annotations  tags
item_id                                       
2       2005-07-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2005-08-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2005-09-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2005-10-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2005-11-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2005-12-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-01-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-02-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-03-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-04-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-05-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-06-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-07-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-08-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-09-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-10-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-11-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2006-12-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2007-01-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2007-02-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2007-03-01      NaN          NaN   NaN
        2007-04-01        2           30    14
        2007-05-01        2           32    16
        2007-06-01        2           36    19
        2007-07-01        2           36    19
        2007-08-01        2           36    19
        2007-09-01        2           36    19
        2007-10-01        2           36    19
        2007-11-01        2           36    19
        2007-12-01        2           36    19
```

Comment: Awesome, but two clarifications: First, as you've done this, I'm left with a redundant item_id column on top of the item_id index. However, it seems I can deal with that by modifying your code to `df.groupby(level='item_id').apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(level='item_id',drop=True).reset_index().set_index('date').reindex(idx,method='ffill'))`. Does that seem reasonable? Second: Why does date no longer show up as an index in the header as in the original dataframe? I don't think this is a problem, but can you explain what's happening? Does the dataframe still have a hierarchical index or...?

Comment: answer to your first part is yes that is reasonable, you can drop on the reset_index to not have a dup. for the second, I think the apply is a bit confused by the index because of the way you are aggregating (so it's dropping the name of the index). You can do another reset_index inside the apply, then at the very end (after the apply, ``.reset_index(drop=True).set_index(['date','item_id'])``, so reset the mi

Comment: Hm...that doesn't actually seem to work (I think the date index applies to each group, so isn't accessible as an index for the actual dataframe). But I think this works in any case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing on Jeff's answer, I consider this to be somewhat more readable. It is also considerably more efficient since only  the droplevel and reindex methods are used.

```
df = df.set_index(['item_id', 'date'])

def fill_missing_dates(x, idx=all_dates):
   x.index = x.index.droplevel('item_id')
   return x.reindex(idx, method='ffill')


filled_df = (df.groupby('item_id')
               .apply(fill_missing_dates))
```